# Sequelize adds order by id when using limit and offset with 'group and order by' and 'include' breaking sql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

Sequelize query without limit or offset produces this SQL:

```
SELECT [abc].[abcid], 
       sum([qty]) AS [abcQty] 
FROM [AS_AS_XYZ] AS [xyz] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AS_AS_ABC] AS [abc] ON [xyz].[abcRef] = [abc].[id] 
WHERE [xyz].[aRef] = N'1' 
      AND [xyz].[bRef] = N'1' 
GROUP BY [abc].[abcid] 
ORDER BY abcQty DESC
```

However, when limit or offset is added to the sequelize query, the query get added with another order by clause on `xyz.id`

```
SELECT [abc].[abcid], 
       sum([qty]) AS [abcQty] 
FROM [AS_AS_XYZ] AS [xyz] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AS_AS_ABC] AS [abc] ON [xyz].[abcRef] = [abc].[id] 
WHERE [xyz].[aRef] = N'1' 
      AND [xyz].[bRef] = N'1' 
GROUP BY [abc].[abcid] 
ORDER BY abcQty DESC, [xyz].[id] 
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

causing error:

> column xyz.id is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

whereas the expected result was

```
SELECT [abc].[abcid], 
       sum([qty]) AS [abcQty] 
FROM [AS_AS_XYZ] AS [xyz] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AS_AS_ABC] AS [abc] ON [xyz].[abcRef] = [abc].[id] 
WHERE [xyz].[aRef] = N'1' 
      AND [xyz].[bRef] = N'1' 
GROUP BY [abc].[abcid] 
ORDER BY abcQty DESC 
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

which will produce paginated result on the grouped resultset on the `abc.abcid`.

Is there a way to hint Sequelize not to include the order by clause on `xyz.id` when adding offset and limit?

Here is the code: (Extracted from larger code, so pardon me if there are typos here or there, but it is pretty much what is there and produces the SQL stated earlier)

```
let query = {};
query.attributes = [
      'abc.abcid',
      [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('qty')), 'abcQty'],
];
   
query.group = ['abc.abcid'];
query.raw = true;
query.where.aRef = 1;
query.where.bRef = 1;
query.order = sequelize.literal('abcQty DESC');
query.include = [{ model: sequelize.models['abc'], attributes: [] }];
query.limit = 10;
query.offset = 10;


let data= await sequelize.models['xyz'].findAndCountAll(query);
```

Comment: You should include the js code that is generating this SQL code so that people can see what you are trying and what might be generating the extra ORDER BY and what might resolve it.

Comment: Found https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7534, looks like the same issue I am hitting

Comment: Used raw queries instead